DELLP 710 problem with detecting the disk with Ubuntu server installation and Proxmox
I recently tried to download Proxmox on my DELLP R710 BIOS Version : 6.0.7 server and It told me that the hard drive can not be detected, so I tried to do it with Ubuntu server and I got the error Block probing did not discover any disks, any idea on which step to take ? I have two S4S of 300 GB, I saw on some other places that I had to run some commands, but when I tried to run them on terminal of the ubuntu server place, it told me it didn't recognize the commands, it also says go from RAID to AHCI, but when I click on F2 I dont have it at all.
I'm really confused, thank you for your help

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include this information.
